# Is my definition of discontinuity correct?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, definition, intuition, epsilon-delta

I think I have made a rigorous and intuitive definition of discontinuity.

> **Definition:** For a function $f(x)$ from $\mathbf{R}$ to $\mathbf{R}$, there is a discontinuity of $a$ at $x_0 \in \mathbf{R}$ if for all $\delta > 0$ around $x_0$; whenever $|x-x_0|<\delta$, there exists an $x$ such that $|f(x)-f(x_0)|$ $\geq a$

How much rigor is my definition?

Comment: "*There is a discontinuity* **of** $\epsilon_1$..."  I have never heard anyone use that phrase.  Also, "For all $\delta$ **around** $x_0$" feels wrong too.

Comment: Alternatively, just look at the definition of continuity. If it is not met, then you have a discontinuity. They are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The negation of a limit condition, Spivak style.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447084/the-negation-of-a-limit-condition-spivak-style). The answers here are exceptional, please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition is *kind of* close, if I'm being generous. To get a full, rigorous  notion of discontinuity, you just need to negate the definition of continuity: a function is discontinuous at $x_0$ if for some $\epsilon_0>0$ and any $\delta>0,$ there exists $c$ so that both $|x_0-c|<\delta$ and $|f(x_0)-f(c)|\geq \epsilon_0$.

Comment: I have edited in accordance with what Jose said in his answer. Please take a look at the edit and say in what way it is *not close*

Comment: What do you mean by $x_0\in x?$ Or discontinuity of $a$? Pretty much, if you formulate it correctly, it will look exactly like what I wrote.

Comment: Shall I replace it with $x_0 \in \mathbf{R}$?

Comment: That would be a good start!

Comment: Please look at my second edit... Now is everything all right?

Comment: It's very close! You say $|x-x_0|<\delta$ before saying that $x$ exists, so those statements should flip. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by $\delta>0$ near $x_0$. Presumably, you mean a ball around $x_0,$ but that's what the second statement is about; $\delta$ should prescribe the radius. I think this is what you're trying to get at, though. I also think you're trying to say for all $\delta$ small enough (all radii small enough), but in fact we can consider any $\delta>0$ (although the case of $\delta$ small is what we're really interested in).

Comment: @Joe also, I don't know what you mean by"discontinuity of $a$.

Comment: There is a sudden jump of $a$ (at $x_0$) in the function. That is what discontinuity means, right?

Comment: Okay, I see what you're trying to say. We don't usually quantify the jump, and in fact you can have discontinuities without jumps (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities). We say that there is a discontinuity at a.

Comment: $|x-x_0|<\delta$ says about the set of different values of $x$ we are interested in. And from those values of $x$ we say there exists an $x$ such that $|f(x)-f(x_0)| \geq a$. So why is there a need to flip the statements.

Comment: You said "whenever $|x-x_0|<\delta,$  there exists an $x$ such that..." I'm saying this is strange because you say $|x-x_0|<\delta$ before introducing $x$.

Comment: Also, it comes down to the logical structure. For continuity, it is $(\forall \epsilon>0)(\exists\delta>0)(\forall x)(|x-x_0|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon).$ Negating this gives $(\exists \epsilon_0>0)(\forall\delta>0)(\exists x)(|x-x_0|<\delta \wedge |f(x)-f(x_0)|\geq \epsilon_0)$.

Comment: I have introduced $x$ in the statement: "For a function $f(x)$ from $\mathbf{R}$ to $\mathbf{R}$" Or shall I need to say "For a function $f(x)$ of $x$ from $\mathbf{R}$ to $\mathbf{R}$" in the beginning.

Comment: You just say a function $f$. We don't specify $x$, yet. You specified $x_0$ at the beginning, so the function will be discontinuous at $x_0$. We don't specify anything else.

Answer (score 0):

There is zero rigor, because:

1. “For all $\delta$ around $x_0$” means nothing.
2. You don't say whar $x_0$ is.
3. The expression “the greatest value of $\lvert f(x)−f(x_0)\rvert$” is undefined.
4. The number $\varepsilon_1$ is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition doesn’t quite work; “largest” may not exist (what if there is an infinite sequence approaching a bound, for example). Using maximum won’t work, you’d need to use supremum. You could simply replace “greatest value of” with “there exists an $x$ such that”, and then your definition works.

Comment: Please look at my edit... Now is everything all right?

Comment: The gist is correct. The maths is so garbled it is unusable.

Comment: Now what makes it *that* garbled? I have explained everything simply